# Web browser engines and special character rendering

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

I'm pretty amazed by this. Chrome, Safari, Opera and Firefox all have their own version of HTML Character entities. I just don't understand that the rendering of the symbols is defined internally by the browser. So somewhere in my browser app code, there are specifications for there own rendering of the HTML Entity for snow man:

[image]

Or compare the almost radical size differences between the recycle sign and the double square sign between Chrome or Safari and Firefox: http://marckremers.com/SO/test.html
In Opera it doesn't even display the double square.

I'm totally confused and actually disappointed by the short sited-ness of browser companies.
Here, they had an amazing opportunity to offer web developers and designers a standardised set of symbols for all manner of UI. But no, they all make their own quirky versions, which means we cannot rely on them for consistent web design.

My question: Is there a way to show these symbols consistently?
Is there an official snowman? (just as an example, it could be any of the hundreds of symbols available)

Finally please go here to investigate the sheer difference of renderings (flick through browsers to see)

http://copypastecharacter.com/

EDIT
After looking further, it's obviously related to Webkit, Gecko and Presto (Opera) rendering engines, not necessarily different browsers. Safari and Chrome render exactly the same snowman.

Comment: The downvote isn't mine as this is an interesting question, but is this not a font issue rather than a browser one? Can you try specifying a `font-family`?

Comment: I slightly modified the 'marck...' URL, `hmtl` to `html`. Hope this is what you wanted to post...

Comment: No it's not. I can't believe some people. This is an entirely legitimate question. Font's have nothing to do with it. And in fact I've specified Arial to prove that now.

Comment: You should always use character entities not the symbol

Comment: @RGBK: the graphics itself are just not standardized. So I think it's not a fault of the browser companies... just another (maybe poor) standard. Did not downvote either.

Comment: @david Not if you specify `<meta charset="utf-8">`. If unspecified, and character entities used instead, same results, as seen here http://marckremers.com/test2.html. Thanks.

Comment: @home point taken, it may be the standard itself, not the browsers who maybe didnt have a standard to work with form the beginning. Would just love to know the background story with this free reigns approach. And it seems like hard work, to have to come up with designs for 100s of entities. And alos interesting is that Safari and Chrome both use the same snowman, so that implies it's webkit rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer... the snowman's decimal representation is `9731` as specified at http://copypastecharacter.com/:

```
<span data-decimal="9731" data-entity="&amp;#9731;" data-id="45739" title="Snowman">☃</span>
```

It's hexadecimal representation is `0x2603`. Looking up this character at [unicode.org/charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) tells us we should look into [this document](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2600.pdf).

Its **Fonts** section states:

> The shapes of the reference glyphs used in these code charts are not
>   **prescriptive**. Considerable variation is to be expected in actual
>   fonts. The particular fonts used in these charts were provided to the
>   Unicode Consortium by a number of different font designers, who own
>   the rights to the fonts.

**Conclusion**

The glyphs are just not standardized, you cannot rely on its graphical representation. It may depend on the font as well as the application you use to display the symbols (the application or browser may use an internal non-OS font). Btw: on my box (Ubuntu 11.04) the symbols look exactly the same in Firefox (7.0.1) and Chrome (15).

The standard pleased us with two different snowmen - with and without snowflakes in background :-)

Comment: Thanks guys. I think this is a pretty good answer to the reasons behind. My solution to this problem will be using SVG combined with Ample SDK, which allows SVG graphics to be used in all browsers even IE 5.5. Thanks